# How to find resolution of video/image file in Android

Tags: android

I want to know what is the resolution(height, width) of my media file (video/image) in Android.

I have my file path and it can be stored in internal or external storage.

I came across some APIs like `MediaStore`, `Media` etc. but don't know how to use them.

Can anyone tell me what is best efficient way to retrieve this meta data with least overhead?

Comment: What u have try ? can we have code please ?

Comment: What have you tried? Images and Video are treated differently. For Images you can simple load it into a Bitmap and get the resolution form that.

Comment: @NiravRanpara he just asking to know about MediaStore, Media or code for retrieve this meta data with least overhead? so they dnt have to need show code for now..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the way:

**For Video**

```
MediaMetaDataRetriever mdr = new MediaMetaDataRetriever();
mdr.setDataSource("file_path");
int height = Integer.parseInt(mdr.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriver.METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_HEIGHT));
int width = Integer.parseInt(mdr.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriver.METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_WIDTH));
```

**For Image**

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("file_path");
bitmap.getHeight();
bitmap.getWidth();
```